# Limiting Retained Emails

Tags: email, ios

Is there any way to set a limit so that thousands of emails aren't downloaded from my email server and stored as copies on my iPad Air running 8.12?  Early version of ios for my old iPad allowed me to set a limit through [Settings] which worked great.  If I needed to find a specific email that wasn't stored on my iPad, the search function went to the server looking for it.